# Ubuntu 14.04, wifi interface disappeared

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ubuntu-14.04

A few days ago wifi network interface on notebook disappeared. Before that all works fine. There is information

Notebook model `sudo dmidecode`

```
System Information
Manufacturer: Sony Corporation
Product Name: SVF1521F1RW
Version: C10KA1KR
```

`lspci`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
08:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5209 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
0e:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
```

So I see wifi controller `07:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)`

`iwconfig`

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
eth0      no wireless extensions.
```

`sudo rkill list all`

```
0: sony-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: sony-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Last two updates

```
Start-Date: 2018-01-19  14:22:44
Upgrade: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0:i386 (2.30.7-0ubuntu1.7, 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.8), transmission-gtk:i386 (2.82-1.1ubuntu3.1, 2.82-1.1ubuntu3.2), multiarch-support:i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.13, 2.19-0ubuntu6.14), transmission-common:i386 (2.82-1.1ubuntu3.1, 2.82-1.1ubuntu3.2), iproute:i386 (3.12.0-2ubuntu1.1, 3.12.0-2ubuntu1.2), libisccc90:i386 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.16, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.17), libc6:i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.13, 2.19-0ubuntu6.14), libc6-dev:i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.13, 2.19-0ubuntu6.14), libisc95:i386 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.16, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.17), libbind9-90:i386 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.16, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.17), libdns100:i386 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.16, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.17), liblwres90:i386 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.16, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.17), gir1.2-gdkpixbuf-2.0:i386 (2.30.7-0ubuntu1.7, 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.8), libc-dev-bin:i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.13, 2.19-0ubuntu6.14), libisccfg90:i386 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.16, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.17), dnsutils:i386 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.16, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.17), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common:i386 (2.30.7-0ubuntu1.7, 2.30.7-0ubuntu1.8), bind9-host:i386 (9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.16, 9.9.5.dfsg-3ubuntu0.17), libc-bin:i386 (2.19-0ubuntu6.13, 2.19-0ubuntu6.14), iproute2:i386 (3.12.0-2ubuntu1.1, 3.12.0-2ubuntu1.2)
End-Date: 2018-01-19  14:23:44

Start-Date: 2018-01-21  19:19:46
Install: linux-headers-4.4.0-109-generic:i386 (4.4.0-109.132~14.04.1, automatic), linux-image-extra-4.4.0-109-generic:i386 (4.4.0-109.132~14.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-4.4.0-109:i386 (4.4.0-109.132~14.04.1, automatic), linux-generic-lts-xenial:i386 (4.4.0.109.92, automatic), linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic:i386 (4.4.0-109.132~14.04.1, automatic), linux-headers-generic-lts-xenial:i386 (4.4.0.109.92, automatic), linux-image-generic-lts-xenial:i386 (4.4.0.109.92, automatic)
Upgrade: linux-firmware:i386 (1.127.23, 1.127.24), xserver-xorg-core:i386 (1.15.1-0ubuntu2.9, 1.15.1-0ubuntu2.11), xserver-common:i386 (1.15.1-0ubuntu2.9, 1.15.1-0ubuntu2.11), xserver-xephyr:i386 (1.15.1-0ubuntu2.9, 1.15.1-0ubuntu2.11), linux-libc-dev:i386 (3.13.0-125.174, 3.13.0-139.188), linux-kernel-generic:i386 (3.19.0-32, 4.4.0-lts1)
End-Date: 2018-01-21  19:25:31
```

I did not reboot notebook after updates and before interface is disappeared. I don't know where to looking for

Comment: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 -> https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/installing-broadcom-wireless-drivers